# SQL Squirrel - Returning results based on length of field

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm trying to return results where the character length is `>= 6`. However, the query (below) is returning results with a text length less than `6`.

```
select a.column1, b.column2, b.column3, b.column4, b.column5  
from test.table a
     inner join test.table b
           on a.row= b.row
where char_length(b.column3) >= 6
```

Results for b.column3 include:

```
Four
Four
Four
Five
Five
SixSix
SixSix
SixSix
```

When all I want are results with a character length greater or equal to `6`.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the backend database? What do you see if you add char_length(b.column3) to the select list? What is the data-type of b.column3?

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: @AlexK.Adding char_length(b.column3) to the select list shows a char_length of 6 next to text fields that should only be four characters. Forgive me if this isn't the answer you're looking for, but the data is stored on multiple places.. AS400 and a SQL server.

Comment: If your `column3` is a `char` column, all values are padded with empty spaces to fill the size of the column. Try adding a `TRIM`, `RTRIM` or an equivalent

Comment: add `concat('|start|', b.column3, '|end|') test` to your select clause.  This will make space characters more visible.

Comment: @JoshPart Do I need to create a sub-table with the trimmed values and join on that table, then?

Comment: @scareware not necessarily; just change your `where` clause to `where char_length(trim(b.column3)) >= 6`. You'll also want to `select trim(b.column3) as column3`

Comment: @JoshPart That did the trick. Thanks! I need to remember to apply the same logic I would use in, say, Excel, to SQL.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQuirrel is just a SQL tool that can be used against many DBMS.

Comment: @scareware You're welcome. I'll post an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your `b.column3` is a `char` column; if that's the case, all values in that column are padded with empty spaces so all the values have the same lenght as the column lenght. You have to `trim` the values in order to check their real lenght:

```
select a.column1, b.column2, trim(b.column3) column3, b.column4, b.column5  
from test.table a
inner join test.table b
on a.row= b.row
where char_length(trim(b.column3)) >= 6
```

Note that the `trim` function depends on which DBMS you are using i.e. SQL Server doesnt' have it, you should use `RTRIM` instead if that's the case.